# Mini-ITX Case that would take ~6 SATA Hard Drives

Tags: nas, mini-itx

Thinking about maybe building my own NAS. I would go with Raid 5, and would like maybe about 6 SATA drives:

- There a mini atx case that can hold this many drives (Non-Rack ideally)
- What sort of power will I need?
- Any way this won't be pretty loud?

Comment: I would like to see an answer to this as well. I assume you mean 6 standard hard drives (not laptop drives)?

Comment: Ya, I was thinking 3.5 form factor

Comment: Hmm.. maybe http://www.quietpc.com/us-en-usd/products/pc-cases/fd-array-black

Comment: Or maybe http://www.silentpcreview.com/fractal-r2?

Comment: Related: Can someone suggest a mini-ITX motherboard that support 6 drives in a RAID?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Lian Li's [PC-Q08](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811112265&cm_re=Lian_Li-_-11-112-265-_-Product)?

Comment: I'm doing basically the same thing as soon as WHSv2 comes out and I've been frantically looking for workable boards and cases.
Here are a couple boards I've been contemplating:
ZOTAC NM10-DTX
Atom/Ion, 6 SATA ports, 1 x16 slot, 1 x1 slot
Sapphire IPC-AM3DD785G
Only 4 SATA ports but AM3 socket so it will take an AMD Athlon II X4  605e 45W TDP proc.
Zotac H55ITX-A-E
6 SATA port goodness, all the advantages of the LGA 1156 chipset, overly power hungry i3/i5 required.
GIGABYTE GA-2AIEV-RH
Only AM2+ but will supposedly still support the AM3 605e, 6 SATA ports, PCIe x16 slot but only supports x8.

Comment: Plenty of other differences, some have Native Wifi, some have add on wifi via a mini PCIe slot, some support DDR2 others DDR3, different onboard GFX, support for 5.1/7.1+1, etc.
I'm looking ideally for a true AM3 board with full DDR3 support, 6+ (7+ really but I doubt that will ever happen) SATA ports, DTX would be nice with an x1 and an x16 slot, 7.1+ support for streaming audio through a wifi home audio setup, descent integrated GFX would be nice too.
Of course I'll probably never get most of these things but I can dream can't I?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's what you're looking for, but most Mini-ITX boards will fit in a standard ATX case.
Most HD's pull around 10w+ each, so an normal Mini-ITX powersupply probably isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Actually the usual drives for home servers, LP models, take around 6.5W when seeking: http://www.silentpcreview.com/article1216-page5.html

Answer (score 1):

Even through some time has passed and you most likely already have a case I would recommend a Fractal Design Array R2 which I use for my Network Storage. It takes up to 6 3.5" devices and 1 2.5" device and just looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do with 4:  [Chenbro ES34069](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811123122).  I've never seen a mini-ITX chassis hold more than 4.

Edit:  I stand corrected.  The Fractal case in the comment above looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using picoPSU or similar, I recommend using low-power drives. Their performance is within striking distance from their 7200rpm counterparts, and their noise levels and power requirements are more modest. If you look at [table on this article], you can easily find LP drives that take 6.5W or less when seeking, compared to around 10W of 7200rpm drives.